# Best way to work with Jetson TK1 and ubuntu 16.04 LTS with ROS Kinetic

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, jetson-tk1

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have a development setup around Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and ROS Kinetic and if possible we would like to interface it with a Jetson TK1 in a multimachine ROS setup.
Looking around i haven't found any obvious solution, but have considered the following scenarios which might be possible:

1. Install ubuntu 16.04 armhf and download ROS kinetic as binary.
2. Install the default Nvidia linux image (ubuntu 14.04 I think) and compile ROS Kinetic from source.
3. Install the default Nvidia linux image and install ROS Indigo as binary.

Which of these possibilities would be most feasible (if any)?
Or is there another option for setting up the system?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242245/best-way-to-work-with-jetson-tk1-and-ubuntu-16.04-lts-with-ros-kinetic/) by [FOXTER](https://answers.ros.org/users/26976/foxter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2016-08-23

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kPanesar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20725/kpanesar/) on 2016-09-22**:
I'm looking for an almost identical setup with Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS Kinetic. I tried to upgrade my Jetson TK1 from 14.04 to 16.04 with the automatic upgrade but, needless to say, it didn't go so well. The Jetson fails to load the kernel properly. I now have to figure out how to revert it to 14.04.

**Comment by [kPanesar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20725/kpanesar/) on 2016-09-22**:
With the latest JetPack, it seems that there is no support for 16.04 on the TK1. So I think sticking with the last two options might be best. If you haven't already, I will try to install ROS Kinetic from source on the Jetson hopefully in the next few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with Jetson TX1 lately, and I chose the default Nvidia linux(Ubuntu 14.04, armhf) with ROS Jade. It works just fine for now without big problems.

You can follow this guide [Ubuntu ARM install of ROS Jade](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/UbuntuARM).

Hope it helps you.

---

Originally posted by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) with karma: 763 on 2016-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0